# Iterating through a List Object in JSP

Tags: java, sql, spring, jsp, jstl

I am working on a project to try and teach myself spring and struts. I am currently stuck on a JSP page. I have a pojo class with variables eid and ename with getters/setters, I also have a table in sql with the same values with six populated rows.
I am accessing my database through a `JdbcTemplate` and have stored the result in a list, I then passed this list to my action page in which I set it as a `request.setAttribute("empList",eList)`. In my jsp page I call that attribute and then try to iterate through it using `JSTL`.
 However nothing shows up, I know that my list variable has data in it since i checked it using the expression tag `<%=eList%>` and objects show up like this:

```
[org.classes.database.Employee@d9b02, 
org.classes.database.Employee@13bce7e, 
org.classes.database.Employee@171cc79, 
org.classes.database.Employee@272a02, 
org.classes.database.Employee@137105d, 
org.classes.database.Employee@1359ad]
```

I thought that maybe I was missing something on jstl but I have jstl-1.2 in my `META-INF/lib` folder. I have also tried to add it in the configure path file and still nothing. I also have the correct tag url. 
Also when I do a simple `<c:out value="Hello"/>`. Hello does print out. So this leads me to believe that my `jstl` is working properly, but when I try iterating through my list using `jstl` nothing shows up at all.
Anyways here is my JSP page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-   8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<% List eList = (List)session.getAttribute("empList");%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Employee Details</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:out value="Hello"></c:out>
<h3>Employee Details</h3>
<hr size="4" color="gray"/>
<table>
<%=eList%>
    <c:forEach items="${eList}" var="employee">
        <tr>
            <td>Employee ID: <c:out value="${employee.eid}"/></td>
            <td>Employee Pass: <c:out value="${employee.ename}"/></td>  
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Before teaching yourself Spring and Struts, you should probably dive a little deeper into the Java language. Output like this

```
org.classes.database.Employee@d9b02
```

is the result of the `Object#toString()` method which all objects inherit from the `Object` class, the superclass of all classes in Java.

The `List` sub classes implement this by iterating over all the elements and calling `toString()` on those. It seems, however, that you haven't implemented (overriden) the method in your `Employee` class.

Your JSTL here

```
<c:forEach items="${eList}" var="employee">
    <tr>
        <td>Employee ID: <c:out value="${employee.eid}"/></td>
        <td>Employee Pass: <c:out value="${employee.ename}"/></td>  
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

is fine except for the fact that you don't have a page, request, session, or application scoped attribute named `eList`.

You need to add it

```
<% List eList = (List)session.getAttribute("empList");
   request.setAttribute("eList", eList);
%>
```

Or use the attribute `empList` in the `forEach`.

```
<c:forEach items="${empList}" var="employee">
    <tr>
        <td>Employee ID: <c:out value="${employee.eid}"/></td>
        <td>Employee Pass: <c:out value="${employee.ename}"/></td>  
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can read `empList` directly in `forEach` tag.Try this

```
 <table>
       <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.empList}" var="employee">
            <tr>
                <td>Employee ID: <c:out value="${employee.eid}"/></td>
                <td>Employee Pass: <c:out value="${employee.ename}"/></td>  
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

Comment: @jjcode you're welcome.`sessionScope` implicit object gives the session scope attribute, so no need to go for script let.Read more about EL implicit objects http://www.journaldev.com/2064/jsp-expression-language-el-example-tutorial

Answer (score 4):

change the code to the following

```
<%! List eList = (ArrayList)session.getAttribute("empList");%>
....
<table>
    <%
    for(int i=0; i<eList.length;i++){%>
        <tr>
            <td><%= ((Employee)eList[i]).getEid() %></td>
            <td><%= ((Employee)eList[i]).getEname() %></td>  
        </tr>
      <%}%>
</table>
```

Comment: Please don't suggest scriptlets as an alternative to EL and jstl.

Comment: @Alaa Abuzaghleh Read about Why Not to Use Scriptlets http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/WhyNotUseScriptlets

Answer (score -1):

```
 <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.empL}" var="emp">
            <tr>
                <td>Employee ID: <c:out value="${emp.eid}"/></td>
                <td>Employee Pass: <c:out value="${emp.ename}"/></td>  
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score -1):

in the case of maven, make sure this dependency is included in the pom file:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -2):

another example with just scriplets, when iterating through an ArrayList that contains Maps.

```
<%   
java.util.List<java.util.Map<String,String>> employees=(java.util.List<java.util.Map<String, String>>)request.getAttribute("employees");    

for (java.util.Map employee: employees) {
%>
<tr>
<td><input value="<%=employee.get("fullName") %>"/></td>    
</tr>
...
<%}%>
```