# Read CSv Data and display total csv data in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I have CSV page and I want read all columns contains CSV file and display in JSP page
I am using following code:

```
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
             wordList = Arrays.asList(country);
            //System.out.println("data is"+wordList.size());

        }
```

How to display ArrayList in JSP page using struts with display tags.

I am not able to write setter methods of properties because I do not know a CSV file contained how many columns in it as it changes file to file

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood from your post is that you have the array list of strings and you cannot display it in JSP. Is this what you want?
A quick solution can be to create a new String from that list, and display just a String.

Comment: my csv file contains following data                fname,lname,address,city,state,country,zip   how this can be display

Comment: well, you have 3 posibilities:
1. jsf
2. scriplet (if you just wanna use the standard JSP library), you use a scriplet to iterate over the list, and output the fields in what manner you want
3. my sugestion above, create a string in which you add a separator after each field, you display this string in the jsp in a div or some tag, and the you use a javascript function to parse and display it in your choosing.

Comment: scriplet: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789207/iterating-through-a-list-object-in-jsp

Comment: jsf+richfaces: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTable.jsf?c=column