# How to Iterate through object property inside a bean in my jsp

Tags: jsp, struts2, iterator, javabeans, valuestack

I have a list products with these attributes :

- Identifier
- Color
- Size
- Supplier

Supplier attribute is an object that has these attributes :

- Name
- Phone

For each product in my list, i'd like to display the identifier & the supplier name. How can i do this with struts / jstl ?

Here is what i'm trying with no success :

```
<s:iterator value="products">
    <tr>
        <td><s:property value="identifiant"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="supplier.name"</td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789207/iterating-through-a-list-object-in-jsp Check this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be getters for each attribute. If the `products` is the property of the `Action` class then it should have

```
//default constructor

public List<Product> getPoducts(){...} //getter
```

In the `Product` class

```
//default constructor

public String getIdentifier(){...} //getter
public String getColor(){...} //getter
public String getPhone(){...} //getter
public String getSupplier(){...} //getter
```

In the `Supplier` class

```
//default constructor

public String getName(){...} //getter
public String getPhone(){...} //getter
```

In JSP

```
<s:iterator value="products">
    <tr>
        <td><s:property value="identifier"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="supplier.name"/></td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JSTL you can try to use the `<c:forEach>` tag like this :

```
<tr>
<c:forEach items="products" var="product>
    <td>
        <c:out value="${product.identifiant}">
        <c:out value="${product.supplier.name}">
    </td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${product.identifier}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${product.supplier.name}" /></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```