# Create Diagram using servlets e Jsp's

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have to create a diagram using Jsp's and Servlets just like the image.
How can I do that? I mean, what logic could I use?

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2G6k.png)

Comment: For such complex diagrams, you can use D3 like library.

Answer (score 0):

jsp file can be created through a table. And using a servlet to send data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="width:100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>${Firstname}</th><th>${Lastname}</th><th>${Age}</th>
  </tr>

<c:forEach items="${empList}" var="employee">
  <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${employee.eid}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${employee.ename}"/></td> 
    <td><c:out value="${employee.other}"/></td> 
  </tr>
</c:forEach>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

[Iterate over elements of List and Map using JSTL  tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148658/iterate-over-elements-of-list-and-map-using-jstl-cforeach-tag)

[Iterating through a List Object in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789207/iterating-through-a-list-object-in-jsp/20789333)