# Extract List<Object> result from query in Java / Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, list, spring-boot, classcastexception

I want to get the value of the result in query.

This is my query / repository file:

```
@Query("select p.name, p.contact_no, p.email_address, p.time_submitted, p.date_due from Application p where p.application_number like ?1")
List<Application> getApplicationSummaryInfo(String application_number);
```

Service:

```
public List<Application> getApplicationSummaryInfo(String application_number);
```

ServiceImpl:

```
@Override
public List<Application> getApplicationSummaryInfo(String application_number) {
    return (List<Application>)applicationRepository.getApplicationSummaryInfo(application_number);
}
```

Controller:

```
List<Application> app_info = applicationService.getApplicationSummaryInfo(application_no);
```

I only know how to access this in jsp file using foreach. But I want to access the fields in my controller file.

I tried doing this:

```
List<Application> app_info = applicationService.getApplicationSummaryInfo(application_no);
System.out.println(app_info.get(0));
```

and I get this result:

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@28bf8e6e
```

then I tried getting the exact "name" field value

```
List<Application> app_info = applicationService.getApplicationSummaryInfo(application_no);
System.out.println(app_info.get(0).getName());
```

but I get this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class com.pckg_name.model.Application ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.rtc_insurance.model.Application is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

really hope you could help me. Thank you!

Comment: What is the actual return value of `applicationRepository.getApplicationSummaryInfo`?  It ain't a `List`, I can tell you that much for free.

Comment: it returns the object [Ljava.lang.Object;@28bf8e6e

Comment: You misunderstand.  I know what that is, but I want to see the signature of that method.  What does it say between `public ??? getApplicationSummaryInfo`?

Comment: what is `Application` class. is it an `entity` or a `dto`?

Comment: @MortezaBandi entity

Answer (score 0):

Might be this will help you.

1. Create a constructor with the fields mentioned in the sql. **(name,contact_no, email_address,time_submitted,date_due)** in Application class.
2. Specify it in query like "select **new Application(name,contact_no, email_address,time_submitted,date_due)** from Application p where p.application_number like ?1".
3. You will get the result in the form of Application object so you can access the fields of that object.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Application` is an entity, instead of :

```
@Query("select p.name, p.contact_no, p.email_address, p.time_submitted, p.date_due from Application p where p.application_number like ?1")
```

`spring-data-jpa` has already a method for you:

```
List<Application> findByApplication_numberContaining(String str);
```

So, there is no need to create the query yourself. Just define the above method inside your `repository` interface.

After that first make sure that your repository method is working as desired.
Then, if you want iterate throught the list inside a JSP page, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789207/iterating-through-a-list-object-in-jsp)
is for you.

Let me know if it fixed the problem.